# When a muscle contracts, does it store potential energy like a spring that is released upon relaxation?

Tags: muscles

A colleague of mine who mainly focuses on clinical chiropractic work claimed recently in a book he wrote that muscles in the pelvic floor have "elastic recoil."

What he means by this is that a muscle behaves like a spring and, upon relaxation, releases potential energy somehow.

I am highly skeptical of this and want to verify if this is true or not.

When a muscle contracts, does it store potential energy like a spring that is released upon relaxation?